# Absolute paths in CSS

Tags: css, url, internet-explorer-8, path, absolute

I want to use absolute links in CSS to load some of the styling content, since the widget I am developing can be integrated in other sites. And the problem for me currently is determining the way to refernce that content- since the integrators may be using http or https as the protocol.

I tried both https and protocol-agnostic url's, but the problem is IE8 which either displays a content security warning when using https over http (example 1), or does not load the content at all (example 2).

The problem is that I still need IE8 support.

```
/* Example #1: */ background-image: url('https://localhost/img/image.png');
/* Example #2: */ background-image: url('//localhost/img/image.png');
```

Any hints on achiving this?

Comment: So the images are loaded from your site, and the CSS is included in their sites? Why not also load the CSS from your site?

Comment: Why do you not want to use an absolute path instead of URL?  `url(/img/image.png);` for instance.  It will be constant for all the users

Comment: Have you tried ://localhost/img/img.png? I believe IE8 on supports the :// to inherit the pages https or http protocol.

Comment: Sadly they are using the CSS files I have to host, i know it's not the best solution.

Comment: I will try the :// version - hopefully that will work in all browsers.